# Linux HID APIS similar to Windows HID APIs

Tags: linux, api, hid

I am looking for corresponding Linux HID APIs similar to what is mentioned on Microsoft this page :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj126202(v=vs.85).aspx

Basically functions corresponding to DataMovement :

```
Data Movement
The following list identifies HID API that an application can use to move data back and forth  between the app and a selected device.

HidD_GetInputReport
HidD_SetFeature
HidD_SetOutputReport
ReadFile
WriteFile
```

I have two directions currently to :

-> Install the wine framework and try use the Windows Application(utilizing HID Apis)

-> Second to Use the Corresponding Linux HID Apis(dark area for me)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

A cross-platform HID API library is [HIDAPI](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) (under the hood, it uses the ReadFile/WriteFile stuff for Windows and libusb for Linux). I have never used it so I cannot vouch for it.

If all you need is SetReport and GetReport, then it may be easier to operate on *hidraw* devices in Linux. I use this technique for [ltunify](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/). You can discover which `/dev/hidrawX` device belongs to a device by querying sysfs ([example](https://git.lekensteyn.nl/ltunify/tree/ltunify.c?id=1938dc08d1b0111f4eb236e4b920a321e78cb5da#n1142)).

Once you have a device (say, `/dev/hidraw0`), then you can open it for reading and writing and use the POSIX `read()` and `write()` functions. You may hit a permissions issue, but that is solvable by changing the permissions of the device, either manually (`setfacl -m u:$USER:rw /dev/hidraw0`) or with a udev rule such as [42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules](https://git.lekensteyn.nl/ltunify/tree/udev/42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules).

Since you need to support both Windows and Linux platforms, I think that you are better off with using the HIDAPI library mentioned before.

Comment: How do I know wether my device is hidraw in Linux or Not?

Comment: Every device registered to the HID subsystem always gains a hidraw device (unless the CONFIG_HIDRAW feature is disabled in the kernel config).

Comment: Have you ever got any success in sending the Output report and then getting the corresponding input report.I tried the first link you mentioned(from signal - HIDAPI) but the input report always yields the the data elements being sent in the buffer of the previously sent Output report.Weird !!!

Comment: @Raulp I haven't used HIDAPI, so you should read its documentation whether this is expected or not (remember to check error conditions if any). Use wireshark and usbmon to find out whether the packets are expected or not. See [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121367/8250) for some filters that may be useful for limiting the output.