# Is hid.dll part of KMDF or UMDF?

Tags: linux-kernel, hid, kmdf, umdf

I am trying to figure out if hid.dll is a part of KMDF or UMDF or none.
I generally use it in my C# program like this :

```
[DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern Boolean HidD_GetInputReport
    (SafeFileHandle HiddevObject,
    Byte[] lpReportbuff,
    Int32 ReportbuffLen);
```

I wanted to use a similiar one for `Linux`.What considerations i have to use.
The application where i am using it is for interacting with a sensor device.

Comment: Shouldn't the question be "how can I interact with a HID sensor device in Linux"?

Comment: I had asked similar Qs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528522/linux-hid-apis-similar-to-windows-hid-apis , but i wanted to know the structure of it for better understanding, feel free to edit the Qs.

Answer (score 0):

HID.dll is a user mode library that provides support routines to obtain information about a Hid collection. HID.dll communicates with HIDClass driver, HIDClass.sys is a windows kernel mode driver for HIDclass device setup class. With HID.dll you dont have to write your own device driver for HID class device.

what sensor devices are you working on?